# Has Firefox's Inspector gone mad?

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

How can Firefox compute a 1px border for a TD styled to have `border: 0`, and how can the Firefox web inspector show me that indeed, the border is styled to `0px` yet, at the same time, it ends up being `1px`?

This is screenshot of the Firefox web inspector:

[image: screenshot]

And the innocent css it refers to a line 21 is:

```
.smart-table-tr-active td {
    border: 0;
}
```

And there are no other overwriting rules shown by the inspector. And it works perfectly fine in Chrome and IE8+... The "insanity" with a 1px border out of nowhere only happens in Firefox (clean profile, no extensions, latest version - 17.0.1 on Windows 7 64bit).

[Link to sample](http://inprogress.neuronq.ro/tedon1/) (click a row to "expand" it and inspect the TDs of the expanded row. (Yeah, there's a bit of Javascript "DOM surgery" behind the scenes, but still, I'd expect a mature browser like Firefox to "keep a cool head" and do its job, even the Inspector...)

Comment: Got a link to the offending page?

Comment: No, Firefox's inspector has certainly not gone mad. I don't even need to read your question to reason that.

Comment: @BoltClock just added it

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Well, I stick to my religious belief that all browsers except Chrome are insane, but still, I didn't expect IE8 to exhibit more sanity than Firefox 17... sigh...

Comment: That's funny; I just took part in an anti-Chrome circlejerk not many hours ago where we agreed IE was saner than Chrome :)

Comment: Anyway, back to the topic at hand; the reason why you see 1px even though the computed value is 0px is because 1px becomes the *used* value. As to why Firefox uses a value of 1px, I don't know yet. I have to examine the page and the code closely, which I can only do later.

Comment: @BoltClock err, my bad for the link, it was the LESS version that IE chokes on at that link, now updated it to the compiled css... refresh now :)

Comment: Btw, same issue is present in Firebug.

Comment: There is a difference between Firefox and Chrome in rendering. When you click on a row to expand it, Chrome renders an additional horizontal line (border) below the expanded row. Have you noticed this?

Comment: @NeuronQ: with all due respect Firefox have some excellent developer extensions which make it very handy for developers

Comment: @BoltClock in a way you're right: in Chrome things that you'd expect to work, like absolutely positioning things inside table cells, just work, but then you go to other browsers like Firefox and you find out that it doesn't work because it's not according to some standard... but in a way Chrome manages to do exactly what my intuition expects to happen, 100% of the time, even if its not "the right thing to do"... otoh, if browsers would always do "the right thing" (by standards), we wouldn't need to have these conversations, and this would be even better :)

Comment: @naveen no disrespect for FF, the dev tools are awesome and this was just a weird corner case... but I hope they don't put too much focus on the eye candy and "fancy stuff" at the expense of basic stability - at the end of the day what I expect from a browser is the same that I expect from an OS: 1. act like it doesn't exist, eg. stay out of the way (aesthetically too) 2. be predictable and stable above all else, and 3. be "fixable" when stuff inevitably breaks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of your issue is in your CSS file:

```
table.smart-table td {
    border-collapse: separate;
    /*position: relative;*/
}
```

You're setting the `border-collapse` property on TD elements. But, that property **doesn't apply** for TD elements, so it's **discarded**. Instead, [it only applies to TABLE elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#borders).

Change your CSS rule to this:

```
table.smart-table {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

and your issue will be resolved. Setting separate borders will make sure that the borders aren't shared (as Boris explained in his answer).

Answer (score 4):

It's 1px because the table is using collapsed borders and the top border on the cell in the *next* row is 1px.  But in the collapsed border model the top border of the next cell (and row, since they collapse) is identically the bottom border of this cell (and row), so they show up with the same value...  More precisely, each one gets half of the border in a bizarre way, but there may not really be a good way to represent that in the inspector.

Read here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#collapsing-borders

Comment: thanks, that explains the source of the "insanity"... though the "cure" for me was simply putting `border-collapse: separate;` in the right place so I'll vote Sime Vidas' answer (I'd choose both if I could)